# Multi threaded reading from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, file

My application uses text file to store data to file.
I was testing for the fastest way of reading it by multi threading the operation.
I used the following 2 techniques:

1. Use as many streams as NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable. Each stream is on a different thread. Divide total no of lines in file equally for each stream. Parse the text.
2. Only one stream parses the entire file and loads the data in memory. Create threads (= NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS - 1) to parse data from memory.

The test was run on various file sizes 100kB - 800MB.
Data in file:

```
100.23123 -42343.342555 ...(and so on)
4928340 -93240.2 349 ...
...
```

The data is stored in 2D array of `double`.

**Result:** Both methods take approximately the same time for parsing the file.

**Question:** Which method should I choose?

Method 1 is bad for the Hard disk as multiple read access are performed at random locations simultaneously.

Method 2 is bad because memory required is proportional to file size. This can be partially overcome by limiting the container to a fixed size, deleting the parsed content and fill it again from the reader. But this increases the processing time.

Comment: How do you split the file into many streams in method 1? The threads must start reading at the beginning of a line after all.

Comment: Alternative 3: [Memory-mapped files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file).

Comment: @usr by seeking to a particular position marked for each stream.

Comment: IMO it won't matter unless you use a parallel file system and hardware. The bottle neck will always be at HDD controller. You can only try to keep sequential read order.

Comment: File contains several streams? What does that mean? Can several threads process data from one stream?

Comment: @Dialecticus when did I say that?

Comment: If performance is such a critical issue, can you make your files binary? That will greatly reduce the size of your file and required IO to read it.

Comment: @Vadim I already have a binary format. In addition to that I am supporting a text format.

Comment: There is a problem with all methods if you have a text file, and that it's very hard to go to a specific position in a text file unless you have a "table of contents" which tells at which offsets specific data is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am adding line no in the file, so its pretty easy to seek at a particular position check if I went ahead or am behind, then correct the position.

Comment: Why is it necessary in method 2 to read the whole file before the threads can process the data?

Comment: @Dialecticus it is not necessary! As soon as a predefined no of lines are read the streams start performing their job. But soon the reader falls back, so the streams have to wait until the reader reads the specific no of lines

Comment: I believe you mean "the threads" not "the streams". So reader thread can read and parse file and feed data to shared container, and all other threads can wait on that container and take data as it's available. There would be no big memory requirements in this "method 3".

Comment: Yes thats threads, sorry typo. Its method 2 actually. As I said in the question "Method 2 is bad because memory required is proportional to file size. This can be partially overcome by limiting the container to a fixed size, deleting the parsed content and fill it again from the reader. But this increases the processing time."

Comment: In the case described in your question, my strong suspicion is that nearly 100% of the time in both cases is spent on disk IO (and that in case #1, perhaps the OS is assisting in optimizing the disk reads).  The CPU-"heavy" part - the parsing - is so fast in comparison that it's probably negligible in this case.  So, bottom line, as long as IO dominates, and you have only one non-parallel read device, both methods are to be expected to be about the same.  But, when CPU processing dominates, obviously the read method doesn't matter, so again (memory efficiency aside) both should be the same.

Comment: Reading the file is your bottleneck, and your goal should be to maximize the reading speed. For maximum reading speed you should use memory mapped file and read sequentially. All of the rest of the code should accommodate this primary requirement, but not introduce more. Extending memory with 800 MB probably means swapping memory pages, which hinders the reading of the file, so must be prevented. In essence, don't use so much memory, but you can decide how to achieve that.

Comment: My previous comment ignores extreme cases such as a gigantic number of CPUs for CPU-bound scenarios where either CPU management starts to dominate, or where the average time per CPU becomes low enough that IO again starts to dominate.

Comment: @Dan Yes the I/O is the significant time hog in comparison to the parsing. In method 1 since multiple read are performed at random locations on same hard disk, I was expecting this to be a slower method. But maybe as you suggested Windows7 is optimising this process.

Comment: @Dialecticus from the Wikipedia article I understand memory mapped file is significantly faster than normal I/O. But it also mentions "In some circumstances, memory mapped file I/O can be substantially slower than standard file I/O."

Comment: I don't know if you are in those circumstances. Honestly, I can't imagine what those circumstances can be. You have to spend some time coding to see if memory mapped files are good for your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method 2 has a sequential bottleneck (the single-threaded reading and handing out of the work items). This will not scale indefinitely according to Amdahls Law. It is a very fair and reliable method, though.

Method 1 has not bottleneck and will scale. Be sure to not cause random IO on the disk. I'd use a mutex to have only one thread read at a time. Read in big sequential block of maybe 4-16MB. In the time the disk does a single head seek it could have read about 1MB of data.

If parsing the lines takes a considerable amount of time, you can't use method 2 because of the big sequential part. It would not scale. If parsing is fast, though, use method 2 because it is easier to get right.

To illustrate the concept of a bottleneck: Imagine 1.000.000 computation threads asking one reader thread to give them lines. That one reader thread would not be able to keep up handing out lines as quickly as they are demanded. You would not get 1e6 times the throughput. This would not scale. But if 1e6 threads read independently from a very fast IO device, you would get 1e6 times the throughput because there is no bottleneck. (I have used extreme numbers to make the point. The same idea applies in the small.)

Comment: what's the difference between a single thread reading a file and several threads reading but blocking each other?

Comment: Can you please tell me what you mean by "scale"?

Comment: @Vadim the blocking happens only for the IO, not for the parsing. You can't go faster than single-threaded on a magnetic disk anyway.

Comment: @Cool_Coder scaling means getting better performance with added resources. In this case, think about how fast the application would be with many CPU cores. When you put many cores to work, and they interfere with each other by synchronization, you get little out of additional cores. Perfect scaling means 2x throughput for 2x the number of cores. Not scaling at all means getting 1x the perf.

Comment: @usr - that's what I fail to understand. If you block your IO, then both alternatives become very similar

Comment: "Method 2 has a sequential bottleneck" - can you please elaborate a bit?
"This will not scale indefinitely" - means "This will scale definitely", right?

Comment: @Vadim you assume that IO is the bottleneck. That is not to be assumed. Whether it is or is not, depends on the kinds of computations to be performed on the data.

Comment: @Cool_Coder imagine 1.000.000 computation threads asking one reader thread to give them lines. That one reader thread would not be able to keep up handing out lines as quickly as they are demanded. You would not get 1e6 times the throughput. This would not scale. But if 1e6 threads read independently from a very fast IO device, you would get 1e6 times the throughput because there is no bottleneck. (I have used extreme numbers to make the point. The same idea applies in the small.)

Comment: @usr understood now :)
So you suggest using method 1 but such that:
1. only 1 stream reads at a time.
2. each read should be of large size instead of reading a single line'

Comment: @Cool_Coder yes, that would be perfect. Play around with the IO size a bit to see what makes most sense. It would be best if you could always prefetch one block so that if the current computation is done, a fresh block is already available. If that turns out to be too complex to implement, just use more threads than there are CPU cores. That way there is always one thread ready to take over the CPU when one thread needs to block for IO.

Comment: Excellent suggestion! I have been burning my brain for 2 days with these 2 methods and so far I had achieved nothing. Thanks for your advice. I will implement it and get back to you next weekend. Hope it gives significant advantage. :)

Comment: I have a prediction that implementing large block reads won't, in this specific scenario (with the same sample files and parsing), result in improvement: the reason being that your Method 2 already essentially tests the difference, and performs no worse in your tests, indicating that the OS is already optimizing your IO reads to, effectively, read large blocks in the case of your Method 1.  I'll be curious to see the result!

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Windows uses 256K prefetching reads. This is, by far, not enough to get effectively sequential performance. This is to ensure fairness. Probably, Linux does not use big reads either.

Comment: The OS is free to read more than one 256K block in sequence, and it will do so when possible.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum it is free to do so but it does not as of Windows 2012. Verify using procmon using "Advanced Output".

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting ProcMon.  It may logically decompose reads into 256K blocks; but, for example, doing bulk reads of entire (non-fragmented) files is not speed-limited by the 256K block size - these contiguous reads are known to be quite fast even for hard disk drives.  At least, this is my understanding.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum with advanced output you see what the OS asks the driver to do. What the disk driver does is not visible, but it will certianly not read far beyond that size. I expect it to read exactly that size. I think Windows will keep multiple IOs outstanding, or the disk firmware will read a little ahead into its disk cache. But none of this is on the order of 4MB+.

Comment: *But it will certainly not read far beyond that size* - I don't think that's right.  But this type of issue is rather complex - it's likely not realistic to spell it all out in comments.  But, given that your two methods are running at the same measured speed, it does seem that it's heavily IO bound, rather than bound by CPU processing, the latter which might (or might not) benefit to one extent or another with different forms of parallelism.  To delve much further, I think, would require your posting the specifics of your timing tests & results.  Might be good to graph the scaling results.

Comment: If it were to read far ahead, a) fairness problems would result (the disk being blocked for 100s of milliseconds and b) it is not clear that all data read would be used at all. It is not necessary to read far ahead to keep the disk 100% busy. This matters only in the presence of concurrent disk requests, which are to be resolved fairly.

Comment: There'd only be blockages if the bus buffer becomes filled.  If not, the disk read can continue unimpeded.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer slightly modified 2 method. I would read data sequentally in single thread by big chunks. Ready chunk is passed to a thread pool where data is processed. So you have concurrent reading & processing

Comment: You have to parse the chunks before handing them out because you must hand out whole lines.

Comment: Yes, you're right. What do you think about such scheme: thread A allocate memory for chunk, read file and pass ready chunk to the thread B, that one split chunk on rows and pass it to thread pool

Answer (score 0):

With enough RAM you can do it without single-thread bottleneck. For Linux:

1) mmap you whole file to RAM with MAP_LOCKED, requires root or system wide permissions tune. Or without MAP_LOCKED for SSD, they handle random access well.

2) give each thread a start position. Process data from first newline after self start position to first newline after next thread start position.

PS What is your program CPU load? Probably HDD is the bottleneck.